# sftp vs https for single file transfer

Tags: http, networking, web-applications, ftp

the only difference I know between the two is that sftp has more intermediary steps and is more complicated. even so, are there any benefits at all for using sftp for a single file transfer from both client to server and server to client

Answer (score 0):

if the objective is to share unidirectionally regardless of security use https, if the objective is exchange of information sftp which requires more configuration and is more secure

Answer (score -1):

You can refer https://enterprisedt.com/blogs/https-sftp-best/

Quoting the summary from article:

> "what protocol should be chosen? If your scenario is lots of naive users who need to download only, HTTPS is probably best. But if more sophisticated file transfer is required, use SFTP. For larger file transfers (especially uploads) we recommend SFTP."

Comment: Please use quote formatting for text that is quoted.

Comment: Done. Thanks for suggestion.